# In jQuery, how/why are these three ways of checking that the DOM is setup equivalent?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){});

$(function(){});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){});
```

I'm not sure I completely understand what is happening in #2, and why it is equivalent to the standard way of doing it, #1.

Comment: It's a matter of preference. I like `$(function() {});` better because it's faster to write and easier to remember. And I use `jQuery(function($) {});` when my jQuery script must work along with other Javascript framework that use the `$` identifier. Though, you have to call `jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jQuery` and `$` are actually the same.

If you pass a function into the `$()` function, jQuery basically checks the type of it, and if it's a function, it will execute it when the DOM is ready. It's just Javascript:

```
function myFunc(arg){
  if(typeof arg == 'function'){
    arg.call();
  }
}
```

---

From the jQuery source:

```
// First, jQuery saves the old values of window.jQuery and window.$

// Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
_jQuery = window.jQuery,

// Map over the $ in case of overwrite
_$ = window.$,

...

// Later on, jQuery returns a reference to the actual jQuery object:
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery

...

// and if you use noConflict, it'll replace window.$ (and window.jQuery) with the old values again
noConflict: function( deep ) {
  window.$ = _$;

  if ( deep ) {
    window.jQuery = _jQuery;
  }

  return jQuery;
}
```

If you call the jQuery function, it'll check the argument type:

```
init: function( selector, context ) {

  ...

  else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
    return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
  }
```

Where `rootjQuery` is the same as `jQuery(document)`

Answer (score 0):

A function passed as an argument to the jQuery constructor is bound to the document ready event.